# Decision Tree with Labels on Both Sides of Line

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, tikz-trees, trees, forest

I am trying to generate a decision tree similar to this scanned example:

[image]

Notice that some branches have text on the top as well as the bottom. I have not figured out how to do this. I can get text on the top or bottom, but not both.

I am enclosing a partial solution. I try to Add "Outbreak" as the top label and "0.060" as the bottom label, but it causes the first label to disappear.

```
   \documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes,snakes}
\usepackage{forest}


\tikzset{
    decision/.style={rectangle, minimum height=10pt, minimum width=10pt, draw=black, fill=black!30!white, thick, inner sep=0pt},
    chance/.style={circle, minimum width=10pt, draw=black, fill=black!30!white, thick, inner sep=0pt},
    leaf-chance/.style={isosceles triangle, minimum width=10pt, draw=black, thick, fill=white, inner sep=0pt, shape border rotate=180, outer sep=-\pgflinewidth}
  }

\newsavebox\notgood
\sbox\notgood{\textbardbl}
\forestset{
  declare toks={optimality}{},
  sub optimal/.style={
    optimality={
      node [midway, sloped] {\usebox\notgood}
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]

\scalebox{0.85}{
 \begin{forest}
   %my label/.style={
   %   edge label={node[auto, sloped,pos=.75,anchor=south]{#1}}
   % },
   my label/.style={
     edge label={node[midway,above,font=\scriptsize,text width=1.5cm,align=center]{#1}}
   },
   my below/.style={
     edge label={node[midway,below,font=\scriptsize,text width=1.5cm,align=center]{#1}}
     },
    for tree={
      grow=0,
      child anchor=west,
      anchor=west,
      text ragged,
      inner sep=1mm,
      edge={thick, draw=blue},
      l sep+=30mm,
      s sep+=5mm,
      if n children=0{
        before typesetting nodes={
          label/.wrap pgfmath arg={right:#1}{content()},
          content={},
          leaf-chance,
        },
      }{},
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
       (!u.parent anchor) -- ([xshift=-22.5mm].child anchor)\forestove{optimality} --  (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
    }
    [,decision
      [0.8351,chance,my label=Insure]
      [,chance,my label=Don't Insure, sub optimal      
        [0.8394,chance,my label=No outbreak
        ]
        [,chance,my label=Outbreak, my below=0.060
          [0.8334,chance,my label=Bans only
          ]
          [0.6663,chance,my label=Slaughter
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
\end{forest}
}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I found this previous answer helpful in switching between above/below, but doesn't show how to get both: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177254/80455

Also, this is the same example as [Adding Short Lines Across Decision Tree Branch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251433/80455) (but a different question).

Comment: Do you want to have also only above and only below?

Comment: Yes, I would like the flexibility to have above, below, both, or none.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`edge label` will override any previous value for any particular node. So the first label disappears. But we can use the same method as I used for the `sub optimal` style i.e. declare another option, just like `edge label` and then add it to the redefinition of `edge path`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etex,forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}


\tikzset{
    decision/.style={rectangle, minimum height=10pt, minimum width=10pt, draw=black, fill=black!30!white, thick, inner sep=0pt},
    chance/.style={circle, minimum width=10pt, draw=black, fill=black!30!white, thick, inner sep=0pt},
    leaf-chance/.style={isosceles triangle, minimum width=10pt, draw=black, thick, fill=white, inner sep=0pt, shape border rotate=180, outer sep=-\pgflinewidth}
  }

\newsavebox\notgood
\sbox\notgood{\textbardbl}
\forestset{
  declare toks={optimality}{},
  sub optimal/.style={
    optimality={
      node [midway, sloped] {\usebox\notgood}
    }
  },
  declare toks={edge label below}{},
}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]
\scalebox{0.85}{%
 \begin{forest}
   my label/.style={
     edge label={node[midway,above,font=\scriptsize,text width=1.5cm,align=center]{#1}}
   },
  my below/.style={
    edge label below={node[midway,below,font=\scriptsize,text width=1.5cm,align=center]{#1}}
  },
    for tree={
      grow=0,
      child anchor=west,
      anchor=west,
      text ragged,
      inner sep=1mm,
      edge={thick, draw=blue},
      l sep+=30mm,
      s sep+=5mm,
      if n children=0{
        before typesetting nodes={
          label/.wrap pgfmath arg={right:#1}{content()},
          content={},
          leaf-chance,
        },
      }{},
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.parent anchor) -- ([xshift=-22.5mm].child anchor)\forestove{optimality} --  (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label below}\forestoption{edge label};
  },
    }
    [,decision
      [0.8351,chance,my label=Insure]
      [,chance,my label=Don't Insure, sub optimal
        [0.8394,chance,my label=No outbreak
        ]
        [,chance,my label=Outbreak, my below=0.060
          [0.8334,chance,my label=Bans only
          ]
          [0.6663,chance,my label=Slaughter
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
\end{forest}%
}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: edge labels above and below]

To avoid the crowding, either allow longer labels (increase or remove `text width`) or increase the value of `s sep`.

Removing the restriction on `text width`:

```
   my label/.style={
     edge label={node[midway,above,font=\scriptsize,align=center]{#1}}
   },
  my below/.style={
    edge label below={node[midway,below,font=\scriptsize,align=center]{#1}}
  },
```

[image: longer labels]

Increasing `s sep`:

```
  s sep+=7.5mm,
```

[image: more distant siblings]

Comment: Thank you! Great solution, including the help on spacing.

Comment: @fraserbc I'm somewhat obsessed with `forest` ;). After I finally figured out how to use it (with some help from this site).

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a "hack", but you can simply set an extra label without the `above` or `below` keys. Then using `\\` when you want to switch to the "other line", they will show one above, one below.

So basically, you'll have:

- `my above`
- `my below`
- `my label` (both)

As far as you've showed, this will work. If there is some situation where this behaviour breaks, please specify it.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes,snakes}
\usepackage{forest}


\tikzset{
    decision/.style={rectangle, minimum height=10pt, minimum width=10pt, draw=black, fill=black!30!white, thick, inner sep=0pt},
    chance/.style={circle, minimum width=10pt, draw=black, fill=black!30!white, thick, inner sep=0pt},
    leaf-chance/.style={isosceles triangle, minimum width=10pt, draw=black, thick, fill=white, inner sep=0pt, shape border rotate=180, outer sep=-\pgflinewidth}
  }

\newsavebox\notgood
\sbox\notgood{\textbardbl}
\forestset{
  declare toks={optimality}{},
  sub optimal/.style={
    optimality={
      node [midway, sloped] {\usebox\notgood}
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]

\scalebox{0.85}{
 \begin{forest}
    my above/.style={
        edge label={node[midway,above,font=\scriptsize,align=center]{#1}}
    },
    my below/.style={
        edge label={node[midway,below,font=\scriptsize,align=center]{#1}}
    },
    my label/.style={
        edge label={node[midway,font=\scriptsize,align=center]{#1}}
    },
    for tree={
      grow=0,
      child anchor=west,
      anchor=west,
      text ragged,
      inner sep=1mm,
      edge={thick, draw=blue},
      l sep+=30mm,
      s sep+=5mm,
      if n children=0{
        before typesetting nodes={
          label/.wrap pgfmath arg={right:#1}{content()},
          content={},
          leaf-chance,
        },
      }{},
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
       (!u.parent anchor) -- ([xshift=-22.5mm].child anchor)\forestove{optimality} --  (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
    }
    [,decision
      [0.8351,chance,my above=Insure]
      [,chance,my below=Don't Insure, sub optimal      
        [0.8394,chance,my above=No outbreak
        ]
        [,chance,my label=Outbreak\\0.060
          [0.8334,chance,my above=Bans only
          ]
          [0.6663,chance,my below=Slaughter
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
\end{forest}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @cfr It will go on. But then the diagram would be badly constructed if you need a label that long for a small path. I'd redesign the diagram.

Comment: @cfr Oh that stuck around. I'll remove it.

Comment: Actually, I see the `text width` is in the original code in the question....

Comment: @cfr Yes, but with it the labels are not properly centered.

Comment: (+1) I think it is better without, too. [I'm not sure if I'm the one who introduced them in the first place!]

Comment: @cfr Oh I don't know about that :P